# bash function failed to give a return value

Tags: linux, bash, return, echo

```
$ function sum()
> {
> echo $1 $2;
> return $(($1+$2))
> }
$ sum 1 2
1 2
$ x=$(sum 1 2)
$ echo $x
1 2
```

I really expect $x to be 3. But still seems it's the "echo" result. How to fix my function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `return`. Just echo the sum as:

```
sum() { echo $(($1 + $2)); }
```

Then use it as:

```
x=$(sum 1 2)
echo $x

3
```

`return` (or exit) value from a function is captured using `$?` after calling the function. However using `return` is not recommended as you can only return 0-255 integer values in a function.

Comment: Just for completeness and since 3 it is in range 0-255 it would worth to be mentioned that "return" will be used for the exit code of the function, and could be caught by $?

Comment: One can also `echo` _and_ explicitly `return` the value.